# Using Python to space out (add padding) between block attributes in AutoCAD

Tags: python, autocad

I am trying to create a python script with pyautocad to automate a very time consuming task in my autocad drawings.

Basically, my project inserts a block object called depth from a depth.scr script which looks like this:

> color                     bylayer
> Layer   set T_Depth
> insert  Depth   831581.3266,833944.5959 1   1   0   0.70d
> Layer   set T_Depth
> insert  Depth   831585.0129,833947.7463 1   1   0   0.71d
> Layer   set T_Depth
> insert  Depth   831588.0642,833950.2778 1   1   0   0.70d

Now, bascially I insert around 1000 blcok objects like this. But once imported, the problem is that the annotated attribute value of these block objects gets clustered together and I have to manaully move them around so the drawing looks more clean. I was thinking if it is possible to make a python script which I can run after inserting the block objects, which can create padding/spacing between the annotated attribute values displayed in the module automatically?

As an example, in the pic below, this is a depth block with value 0.70d which I imported.

[image]

[image]

Itself it is ok but in the third image, you can see that with multiple attribute vlaues of different blocks showing, this is unreadble. And I have to manually move the annonations to make it look clear (note that I am talking about the text not the point itself). Is it possible I can create spacing between them automatically?

[image]